# Почему при вводе ДЕТСКУЮ у меня выводит NameError: name 'skazka' is not defined

Tags: python

```
print("Привет! Это твой помощник")
print("Он сможет ответить на все твои вопросы")
print("Если хочешь задать вопрос, пиши)")
wopros1 = input()
if wopros1 == "какое время суток сейчас?":
   print("Введите округлённое число!!!")
   wopros = int(input())
if wopros <= 5 or wopros == 6:
   print('Доброй ночи!')
elif wopros >= 7 and wopros <= 11:
     print('Доброе утро!')
elif wopros >= 12 and wopros <= 17:
     print('Добрый день!')
elif wopros >= 18 and wopros <= 22:
     print('Добрый вечер!')
else:
    print("Убидитесь в правельном написании команды")
if wopros1 == "Расскажи сказку":
   print("Детскую или взрослую?")
   wozrast = input()
if  wozrast == "взрослую":
    print("Длинную или короткую?")
    skazka = input()
if  skazka == "Длинную":
    print("В этот лес завороженный,")
    print("В этот лес завороженный,")
    print("По пушинкам серебра,")
    print("Я с винтовкой заряженной")
    print("На охоту шел вчера.")
    print("По дорожке чистой, гладкой")
    print("Я прошел, не наследил…")
    print("Кто ж катался здесь украдкой?")
    print("Кто здесь падал и ходил?")
    print("Подойду, взгляну поближе:")
    print("Здесь вот когти, дальше — лыжи…")
    print("Кто-то странный бегал здесь.")
    print("Кабы твердо знал я тайну")
    print("Заколдованным речам,")
    print("Я узнал бы хоть случайно,")
    print("Кто здесь бродит по ночам.")
    print("Из-за елки бы высокой")
    print("Подсмотрел я на кругу:")
    print("Кто глубокий след далекий")
    print("Оставляет на снегу?..")
elif skazka == "Короткую":
    print("Последняя туча рассеянной бури!")
    print("Одна ты несешься по ясной лазури,")
    print("Одна ты наводишь унылую тень,")
    print("Одна ты печалишь ликующий день.")
    print("Ты небо недавно кругом облегала,")
    print("И молния грозно тебя обвивала;")
    print("И ты издавала таинственный гром")
    print("И алчную землю поила дождем.")
    print("Довольно, сокройся! Пора миновалась,")
    print("Земля освежилась, и буря промчалась,")
    print("И ветер, лаская листочки древес,")
    print("Тебя с успокоенных гонит небес.")
elif wozrast == "Детскую":
    print("Длинную или короткую?")
    deti = input()
if  deyi == "Длинную":
    print("С Александром Куприным")
    print("(Знаменитым рыболовом!)")
    print("По пруду скользим, как дым,")
    print("Под наметом тополевым.")
    print("Я вздымаюсь на носу")
    print("И веслом каскады рою,")
    print("Он, зажав в руке лесу,")
    print("На корме сидит с блесною.")
    print("Сердце, — бешеный комок,—")
    print("Отбивает: щука-щука!")
    print("Оплываем островок,")
    print("На корме, увы, ни звука…")
    print("Только ивы шелестят,")
    print("Запрокинув в воду шапки,")
    print("Только кролики глядят,")
    print("В изумленье встав на лапки.")
    print("Вдруг, взглянув из-за плеча,")
    print("Я застыл и крякнул… Ловко!")
    print("Александр Куприн, рыча,")
    print("Из воды сучит бечевку…")
    print("Кровожадные глаза")
    print("Полны трепетного мрака:")
    print("— Напоролась, егоза!")
    print("Не уйдешь… Шалишь, собака! —")
    print("Тянет, тянет. Не легко.")
    print("Пузырем вскипает влага:")
    print("Распластавшись глубоко,")
    print("На крючке висит… коряга.")
```

Comment: там то вроде всё правильно , у меня в другом ошибка

Answer (score 0):

У тебя две переменные
wopros и wopros1
ты в них запутался

А переменную skazka ты определяешь ТОЛЬКО если возраст "взрослый"
Если возраст детский  - она не определена

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам [стали доступны комментарии](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос